# chosen width issue inside inactive tab container

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen library to enable easy filtering on a dropdown control and i am facing one issue now.
I am using bootstrap tab control to arrange the items in a form and if i place the Dropdown inside the inactive tab item width of Choosen dropdown is 0 (invisible at all ).

How can i fix this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OriginalItem.AuthorId, (SelectList)ViewBag.LicensorList, "Select", new { @class = "chosen-single chosen-default" })
 $('#OriginalItem_AuthorId').chosen({ no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!" });
```

This is the way i am using chosen library

Comment: Try to [update chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) on [tab shown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)

Answer (score 9):

This is because the width is calculated by Chosen before the dropdown is visible.

There are at least two workarounds:

**CSS workaround :**

```
.chosen-container { 
    width: 100% !important; /* desired width */
}
```

---

**JS workaround** *(on Chosen initialization)* **:**

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen(
    { 
        width: '100%' /* desired width */
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use width in percentage within single quotes:

```
<select chosen width="'100%'" ... ></select>
```

This works also for modal windows in which the content is compiled without being visible (width=0).

A responsive chosen using this technique can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RMAe8c?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is issue of Tabcontainer when we set "AutoPostBack=True" of TabContainer, then it sloves issue of shrinking dropdown width after changing tabpanel.
Please Mark it if it is workable